# Android ViewPager inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im currently facing problem with putting a ViewPager Inside another ViewPager,both swipeable. I have created my first ViewPager with success it contains three pages the middle one is the second(Inside) ViewPager that contains 3 pages inside.

```
| ACTIVITY-1 | VIEWPAGER | ACTIVITY-1 |
         | AC1 | AC2 | AC3 |
```

The parent ViewPager is working fine with it's swipe, but the internal ViewPager is unable to show activities inside and so is not swipeable also.

Parent ViewPager :

```
public class MainSlider extends ActionBarActivity {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_slider);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);        

}
```

Associated XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.example.slidingapp.MainSlider" >

    <android.support.v4.view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter ViewPager :

```
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Also the fragment :

```
   public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView;
        Bundle args = getArguments();

        switch (args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
        case 1:
             rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_first_page, container, false);
            break;
        case 2:
             rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_second_swap, container, false);
            break;
        case 3:
             rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_third_page, container, false);
            break;
        default:
             rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_slider, container, false);
            break;
        }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

code for the child fragment is same as of parent kindly provide any solution for child ViewPager as it's unable to load any activity inside.

Comment: Child(Internal) ViewPager works fine and shows activities when i run it separately out of parent viewpager.

Comment: Are you fixed this problem?

Comment: Hello doing something similar to you and got to the same error. Did you manage to solve your error?

Comment: I did solve the problem and used a library for it. [This](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) is the link.

Answer (score 2):

In case of nested viewPager,  if your child viewpager not visible or not scrolling properly then initialize your child viewpager (pagerAdaper class) using **getChildFragmentAdapter()**

Answer (score 1):

You can display a ViewPager inside another Viewpager.All you have to do is,Let's suppose you have three tabs and you want to display your inner viewapager in second fragment,here's the code to be written in onCreateView of fragment2:

```
viewpager=(ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.innerpager);
    Innerpager innerpagerr = new Innerpager(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewpager.setAdapter(innerpagerr);
    viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}
```

and whatever you want to show in the innerViewpager fragments,design thier layouts seperately for each fragment.Write the below code in FragmentpagerAdpater class as:

```
public class Innerpager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private Context _context;
int num_of_frags = 2;


public Innerpager(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
            return Innerlist.newInstance(0, "one");
        case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
            return Innerlist2.newInstance(1, "two");
        case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
            return Innerlist2.newInstance(2, "Page # 3");
        default:
            return null;
    }
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return num_of_frags;
}}
```

create a new instance of each fragment as following in your fragments:

```
 public static Innerlist newInstance(int page, String title) {
    Innerlist fragmentFirst = new Innerlist();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("100", page);
    args.putString("one", title);
    fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentFirst;
}
```

That's it!! now your main  activity as a Viewpager which controls three fragments namely fragment1,fragment2,fragment3 and inside of your fragment2 you have the above code.Hope this is helpful to you.Happy coding!!

Answer (score -2):

I think its not possible to insert a view pager inside a view pager, because we cant provide scroll for both. You need to create a custom view for inner pager. You can find a better solution [here](http://firstcode.info/example-of-viewpager-with-custom-pageradapter/)